# Where to get a proper dataset collection for bikes and cars

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am doing a project on image classification and I don't know where to get the data-set collection for cars and bikes.Any suggestions to sites for this purpose is welcome.Also please suggest the general size of images to act as a database.

Thanks and regards in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bike and Cars database](http://www.emt.tugraz.at/~pinz/data/GRAZ_02/)

http://www.emt.tugraz.at/~pinz/data/GRAZ_02/

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm

Hope this helps .. Download the bike.zip and cars.zip files and extract it.. If it is correct, click the tick mark to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the reply.I have a doubt and this is stupid,all the images posted in the websites are used as training images,I was wondering how these images could be used to detect bikes and cars that are not present in the database.Any clarifications would be much appreciated.

Comment: @logamadi Pls elaborate more on your project. If you have more question, make it as a separate question

Comment: I am trying to identify the presence of bikes and cars given an image and give an output as whether there is a car or a bike present.There are basically four steps involved in the classification of bikes and cars.They are as follows:(i)SIFT algorithm to detect and get the features of the automobile.(ii)K-means clustering technique to group similar features together.(iii)SVM to determine whether bike or car is present in the image.(iv)Try to retrieve the image if it has a car or a bike.